Возможно ли ускорить отправку сообщений от бота ТГ с прикреплённым медиафайлом?
Проблема следующая, по ТЗ нужно сделать информационного бота с возможностью прикрепления различных медиафайлов (картинки, видео, pdf-ки). Но сообщение не отправляется сразу, ибо после отправки прикреплённые файлы пока загрузятся на сервера ТГ, пройдёт секунды 2-3...
Есть ли способ предзагрузить прикрепления заранее и отправлять просто их id в прикрепление к сообщению? Если и есть, то как это правильно реализовать через Telegraf.js?

Нашёл небольшое решение: Отправлять в открытый канал сами видео, потом копировать ссылку на них и уже её отправлять как видеофайл.
Но это не то, нужна автоматика и желательно не создавая новые "мусорные" каналы/ чаты

Если эти медиа новые, то вам в любом случае придется потратить время на загрузку этих медиа так или иначе куда бы то ни было. Да и 2-3 секунды, видится, не таким уж и большим временем
